# NSDataDetector returns two incorrect matches when date string includes day name

Tags: ios, cocoa, date

I'm writing an iOS 7 app which uses the following code to parse a date from a string:

```
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingAllTypes error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:lastUpdated options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [lastUpdated length])];
NSLocale* currentLoc = [NSLocale currentLocale];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
  if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeDate) {
     NSLog(@"Date : %@", [[match date] descriptionWithLocale:currentLoc]);
  }
}
```

The input string (lastUpdated) looks like this:

> Mon, 03 Feb 2014 16:59:15 GMT

I get two matches from the data detector, neither of which is correct:

> Monday, 3 February 2014 12:00:00 Greenwich Mean Time

and

> Wednesday, 5 February 2014 16:59:15 Greenwich Mean Time

(5th February being the date on which the code was run for this example.) If I manually strip the "Mon, " from the original string, I get a single match, which is the correct result:

> Monday, 3 February 2014 16:59:15 Greenwich Mean Time

But clearly it would be preferable not to have to manipulate the input string as this rather defeats the purpose of using NSDataDetector. If anyone could explain where I'm going wrong, I'd be very grateful. The device on which I'm running this code is iOS 7, the IDE is Xcode 5.02. The locale is UK, timezone London.

UPDATE 2014-02-06. I discovered that it is only strings beginning "mon" which have this problem. If the start of the string is any other day of the week, then only one match is returned and that match has the correct date. If the string begins "mon", then it returns two matches, neither of which is the complete date and time. So presumably "mon" means something to NSDataDetector other than "Monday"?

Comment: Just a thought: have you checked the match to see whether it's matching the entire input string? If it's only detecting the "Mon, 03 Feb 2014", that might explain your first result.

Comment: Thank you, Sixten. That's a good suggestion. I checked and it is definitely being passed the whole string. I also discovered that this only happens when it starts with "Mon". A string starting with "Wed" works correctly, i.e. just one match containing the correct date and time.

Comment: I raised a technical support incident with Apple and they have told me to report it as a bug, which I have done. I'll post an update here if I hear back from Apple.

Comment: @davidrendall Did you get any response from Apple?

Comment: In answer to Giorgi's question, no I never received any response from Apple. The bug remains in the bug reporter database with a rank of "no value". I haven't re-tested this bug in iOS 8 or iOS 9, so it's possible they've fixed it without closing my bug.